# Cannot stop exoplayer: ...SimpleExoPlayer.stop()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

I am using the exoplayer for my android app and it is also working quite fine beside that I am not able to stop the stream. I have a stopplaying method but it throws me the error, that the player is null.

MainActivity.java

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }
    public void initMediaPlayer(){
        context=MainActivity.this;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://stream.mp3");
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(context, "BoomBoxBeilstein"));
        MediaSource MediaSource =
                new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector());;
        player.prepare(MediaSource);
        wl.acquire();
        wfl.acquire();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    public void startPlaying() {

        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onStart();
        initMediaPlayer();
        };

    public void stopPlaying() {
        super.onStop();

        player.stop();
        wl.release();
        wfl.release();


        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

I tried this but I keep getting the error:

````
```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.stop()' on a null object reference
````

I also tried the same with

```
player.release();
```

with the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method `initMediaPlayer()` you're creating new object `SimpleExoPlayer player = ...` and it's stored in local variable but in method `stopPlaying()` you invoke method `stop()` on a field named `player` which is empty as you never assigned an instance of player to this field.
So the solution is any of these two:

- At the end of `initMediaPlayer()` method assign local variable to the field: `this.player = player;`
- Don't use local variable `SimpleExoPlayer player` and assign created player directly to the field so instead of

```
SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector());
```

use

```
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector());
```